# geolocation plugin not working in android mobile

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic4

Ionic information:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.6 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.1.0
   OS     : Windows 10

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : F:\Android\android-sdk\tools;F:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

In that function, I am calling `this.getLocation()` function

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ViewleadPage');
    this.getLocation();       
}    

getLocation(){
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
         this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
         this.lang = resp.coords.longitude;  
         alert(this.lat); 
         console.log('getting location', this.lat);    
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error getting location', error);
        });
    }
```

Plugin name: cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"

I install that plugin and its working fine in the browser but not working on the device.

Is there any solution for it? or any other plugin for it to achieve that functionality?

Comment: Another plugin to use is **Background geolocation**.

Comment: This plugin also works fine if you enable highAccuracy and use maximumAge.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: But it is working very fine in my case.. Is your device GPS working properly?? Or if this plugin does not work you can also use **Background Geolocation**.

Comment: I had also tried with Background Geolocation, but an issue is that in most of the device it will not support and Background Geolocation does not work when I minimize my application. To fetch lat and long need to open an application in mobile.

Comment: Yes you are right **Background geolocation** does not work in iOS properly. I think **Geolocation** plugin is better. What is the error in **Geolocation** plugin??

Comment: And also your **ionic info** shows that you have not installed Cordova CLI may be it is causing error.